# Using .filter() on a horizontal brush

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

I need to create a d3 brush which allows only for expansion/contraction on the right. i.e. I need to prevent the default behavior of move and expansion/contraction from the left.

From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush), looks like this can be achieved by the `filter` function(?) - but I am not seeing how to achieve the above use case. In [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6498000), if I change the `var brush` to

```
var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("start brush", brushed)
    .filter(function(){return event.button;})
    ;
```

to add the `.filter` this is preventing the click on the right side as well :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach using [`.filter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_filter) will work if you check for the target of the mouse event. Your one-dimensional, horizontal brush will be constructed by D3 as follows:

```
<rect class="overlay" pointer-events="all" cursor="crosshair" x="0" y="0" width="960" height="500"></rect>
<rect class="selection" cursor="move" fill="#777" fill-opacity="0.3" stroke="#fff" shape-rendering="crispEdges" x="112" y="194" width="182" height="83"></rect>
<rect class="handle handle--e" cursor="ew-resize" x="289" y="189" width="10" height="93"></rect>
<rect class="handle handle--w" cursor="ew-resize" x="107" y="189" width="10" height="93"></rect>
```

Given this structure you need to filter out events targeted at `<rect class="handle handle--w"/>` and `<rect class="selection"/>`:

```
.filter(function() {
  return !d3.event.button 
    && !d3.select(d3.event.target).classed("handle--w")
    && !d3.select(d3.event.target).classed("selection");
})
```

This will filter out events targeted at the left handle (i.e. a `<rect>` having class `handle--w`) of the brush as well as those targeted at the selection itself. Have a look at the working [demo](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/1b9b08288f520f540f74327dd29d3480).

Additionally, you have to adjust the styles for the cursor to not change its appearance when hovering the left brush handle and the selected area.

```
.handle--w, .selection {
  cursor: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. For some reason, d3 didn't add the `class="brush"` in my [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6498000) -- but that's fine, because I plan to add my own classes anyway.

Comment: @mrbrahman My bad, I was distracted halfway through writing this answer... You are right, the brush elements created by D3 comprise the rects but not the outer group. You are expected to create that group yourself assigning whatever class you see fit. I have adjusted that code, the relevant changes to CSS and the demo, which wasn't even working. Glad it helped anyways!

Comment: Thanks again. Not sure if this warrants a separate thread -- would it be possible to enable mousedown on `selection` (for some other action), but avoid move? Sorry, I'm relatively new to JavaScript as well as D3 and hence all these questions!

Comment: @mrbrahman Although I am not quite sure what you are asking, I am pretty sure it can (easily) be accomplished ;-) As you already mentioned yourself, please post this as a new question; be as precise as possible, provide the relevant code and put a reference back to this question in it, and before long you will likely get a decent answer.

Comment: [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510351/d3-imposing-constraints-on-a-horizontal-brush). Thank you