# Override the default move behaviour of a brush's selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is sort of a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493699/using-filter-on-a-horizontal-brush) question.

I need to create a Horizontal Brush with the below constraints:

1. Allow resize of brush only on the right side
2. That means disable move and resize from left side
3. Clicking on the `selection` should trigger a separate action, and not trigger the default `move` action

I'm able to achieve #1 and #2 using the solution there. This one is expanding on that with the question #3.

Comment: Is the first brush required to stay active, i.e. be adjustable, once the second brush has been added by a click in the first one? Same question for the third and the second one, of course. If only the brush which was added last should be active you could safely remove the previous brush and just append a new one.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! In order to provide a smooth experience, I'd prefer to keep the first brush active even after the second and third was created. In that case, moving the first selection shorter than the second would auto compress the second one to fill the selection of the first one, but re-expanding the first selection would leave the second in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will restrict this to just answer your item 3. about handling clicks on the brush's selection. Expanding on the example from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496900/4235784) to your other question this can be done by using D3's means of registering an event handler on the `<rect class="selection"/>` corresponding to the selection.

```
g.selectAll(".selection")
  .on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
    // Add/enable second brush here.
    console.log("Selection clicked");
  });
```

Have a look at the working [demo](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/d32060182eb661b251930000d9b28fd0).

My other answer already dealt with disabling the default move behaviour, so this will just add a new handler function as a hook for your own code.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I also modified my question to restrict to asking this one thing. Though my intention was to provide a full picture of what I was trying to do, I realized, I should really try to create those nested brushes myself first before just posting them here :-)

Comment: Any idea why the demo works on Chrome, but not on Firefox 57.0.4 (64-bit)?

Comment: @mrbrahman Firefox doesn't expose a global `window.event`, which breaks the code. See [*"ReferenceError: event is not defined error in Firefox"*](/q/20522887). I have updated the demo to use `d3.event` instead.